# Get Youtube address in PHP

Tags: php, youtube

I have got a forum already written in PHP.

I need to detect when someone posts a youtube URL and grab that whole url/string.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545427/youtube-link-regex

Comment: Post to where ? Your form ? And have you taken a look at Regex - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/(http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[^\s]*)/si', $str, $match_urls);
```

This matches youtube video links.

Comment: There's also the short form `http://youtu.be/ID_OF_THE_VIDEO`. I also wouldn't make `http://` and `www` mandatory